# Get properties of QML ListElement

Tags: qt, properties, qml

I have a custom object in QML which uses a Loader to dynamicly loads qml objects and sets properties of it. I want to access all the properties of the ListElement, and pass it trough to the Loader.

```
model: ListModel {
    ListElement {           
        bodySource: "some_object.qml"
        bodyModel: ListElement {
            myProp1: false
            myProp2: ""
            myProp3: 0.0
        }
    }
}

var bodyModelElement = model.get(0).bodyModel.get(0);
for (var propertyName in bodyModelElement)
{
    console.info("propertyName: " + propertyName);
}
```

The propblem with this is that I get also a lot of other property names I didn't expect.

```
qml: propertyName: objectName
qml: propertyName: myProp3
qml: propertyName: myProp2
qml: propertyName: myProp1
qml: propertyName: objectNameChanged
qml: propertyName: __0
qml: propertyName: __1
qml: propertyName: __2
```

Where `__0`, `__1`, `__2` and `objectNameChanged` is of type object
and `objectName` is an empty string

How can I only get `myProp1`, `myProp2` and `myProp3` ?
Or should I just exclude the names starting with an underscore and `objectName(Changed)`

Comment: Not sure it works with such an object, but maybe `if(bodyModelElement.hasOwnProperty(propertyName))` can help to filter to undesired properties out.

Answer (score 3):

`ListElement` operates with roles, not with properties.

From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listelement.html#details)

> ... QML elements contain a collection of role definitions instead of
>   properties...

So since these elements can define some properties for their own needs you cannot reference to properties or loop through in such way.

Btw, `ListElement` in [C++ code](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/qml/types/qqmllistmodel_p.h?h=5.5#n148) is just a `QObject`.

On the other hand, the necessity to loop through roles points to some 
error in code design since the only purpose of `ListElement` is defining a pair `role_name-value`.

If you still want to define some enumerated values within `ListElement` you can define it as a property - array of values.